# Docker - Volumes inside volumes?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I try to start the Docker Jenkins Container (jenkins/jenkins:2.218-jdk11) so that if you create a new Jenkins Container you have all plugins already installed and skip the installation.

For this I have a preinstalled `/var/jenkins_home` (where all the data from Jenkins is located) that Docker uses to start, which works. This home directory doesn't need to be persistent and is only needed for the first startup so it can be copied into the container.

Inside `/var/jenkins_home` there are 2 directories which must be persistent. I have already tried with my own docker file to overwrite `/var/jenkins_home` with my own version which didn't work (maybe wrong configuration?). Do you have any tips how I could implement such a concept?

Comment: Is a custom jenkins image what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: No, the official one. I tried to overwrite `jenkins_home` with my own `jenkins_home` using my own docker file, but it didn't work and I had to do the installation and install all plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can mount [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for the directories you want to persist.

```
$ docker run -v /path/to/persistence:/var/jenkins_home/dir_persisted jenkins-image:2.218
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I know what volumes are. I guess I explained it badly, so I'll try it again: I have a directory on my host that needs to be loaded into the container when the Docker Container starts, or before that, so that Jenkins can access this directory and skip the installation. Within this directory, however, there are 2 folders that need to be stored persistently on my host. I have tried:

Comment: 1.) Container with 3 volumes: 
`/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home`
`/jobs:/var/jenkins_home/jobs`
`/workspace:/var/jekins_home/workspace`
This did not work and the files in `jobs` and `workspace` were written to `/jenkins_home` instead of `/jobs` or `/workspace`.

Comment: 2.) Dockerfile, where I overwrite /jenkins_home with my own directoryss and then mount `jobs` and `workspace` as volume. This didn't work either, because the data in /jenkins_home seems to have been overwritten by Docker again and I had to install Jenkins.

Comment: Have you tries to mount volumes only for the `workspace` and `jobs` folders ?
How about tying to set a different path for the `workspace` folder in `config.xml`, I belive you can do this by setting  `<workspaceDir>`. Hope this heps